# Loop through object with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-promise

I use promises in angular to get some data from the server. In promises success I do

```
promise.success(function (data, status) {                          
  for (i = 0; i <= data.data.length; i++){
    $scope.anArray[i]  = data.data[i][1] ;
  }   
}
```

I do this because `data` that came from the server have this structure

```
{"result":"answered","data":[["jake","508"],["amir","602"],["ben","450"]]}
```

and I ONLY want to get the numbers 508 , 602 and 450. But I always get the same error `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` reffering to this line : `$scope.anArray[i]  = data.data[i][0] ;`.

Those numbers are feeded to a library to create a chart. Sometimes the chart is created, some times is not. Even if it is created, the same error is always there.

I dont know how to fix that error and getting the chart to be always created without any problems. Looks like the code doesnt like the `data.data[i][0]` structure, having a simple array like `data.data[i]` doesnt create an error.

What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: use `angular.forEach()` is way cleaner  and already in the lib core. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: @sbaaaang I chose Paarths answer as the right one because it takes the minimum ammount of editing to fix my code. But your suggestion is also very nice, I even forgot there is the `forEach`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: of course you're welcome, just remember angular.forEach() is exactly a for loop cleaner and more easy to use, makes no sense to use plain js when you have that ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop has an extra execution. You've initialized `i` to `0` but you've also used `<=` which means you are going to execute on `array[array.length]` which is out of bonds. That returns `undefined` and when you try to access the `[0]` index on that undefined you get that error.

Change to

```
for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++){
```

If you're able to do assignment personally I would go with

```
$scope.anArray = data.data.map(entry => entry[1]);
```

and skip the for loop entirely. Note if you want to avoid lambdas this would be

```
$scope.anArray = data.data.map(function(entry) { return entry[1]; });
```

Comment: Yes, I ment to write `$scope.anArray[i]  = data.data[i][1] ;`, I edited my question, so you can erase that part about 0 from your answer too. Also... DUDE, you are right, all I had to do was to erase the = from my for. Thanks